# I am trying to update data but it doesn't get updated in the database

Tags: python, mongodb

I am new to python and Mongo db. What am I trying to do is that I want to update data in my database and code seems to be working fine. But, still the data doesn't get updated in the database.

I have tried functions like update and update_one etc. But still no luck so far.

```
@app.route("/users/update_remedy", methods = ['POST'])
def update_remedy():
    try:
        remedy = mongo.db.Home_Remedies
        name = request.get_json()['name']
        desc = request.get_json()['desc']
        print("S")
        status = remedy.update_one({"name" : name}, {"$set": {"desc" : desc}})
        print("h")
        return jsonify({"result" : "Remedy Updated Successfully"})
    except Exception:
        return 'error'
```

Comment: What ORM are you using? Also, as I see here you update values without saving them but I cannot be 100% sure as long as I don't know what your mapper is.

Comment: Using pymongo with flask I presume? ( should add those tags to your question ). If there is no exception thrown it's likely nothing was matched by the update. Check the `name` in your POST request and that you are receiving it correctly and also check that there actually is something in the database matching that `name` being sent in the request. Also check the collection since `remedy = mongo.db.Home_Remedies` looks odd. If anything the `db` is most likely something else.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your `update_one` call is looking for a document that doesn't exist. If the query on a vanilla update doesn't return any documents then no update operation will be performed. Make sure that a doc with the field `{"name" : name}` 
actually exists. You could also check the return value from the `update_one` to ensure an update happened. See [UpdateResult](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/results.html) for details.